# how create form submit data based on the JSON data format that given from the backend in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to vue and have some trouble and need help to fix it. So I have this backend Json data format and this format is for posting/submitting a data:

```
{
    "name" : "Water",
    "sample_groups": [
        {
            "id_group": 1,
            "price": 75000,
            "tests": [
                {
                    "id_test": 1,
                  "min_req": 10,
                  "max_req": 20
                },{
                    "id_test": 8,
                  "min_req": 1,
                  "max_req": 14
                },{
                    "id_test": 9,
                  "min_req": 1,
                  "max_req": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My question how to make the submit form for that kind of json data structure? So far i've tried this.

```
<div class="vx-col md:w-3/5 mb-base">
    <vx-card :title="card_title" class="vs-con-loading__container" id="master-test-div-right">
        <form action="#" v-on:submit.prevent="submitData">
            <div class="vx-row mb-6">
                <div class="vx-col sm:w-1/3 w-full">
                <span>Sample</span>
                </div>
                <div class="vx-col sm:w-2/3 w-full">
                <vs-input class="w-full" v-model="form_data.name" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <vs-divider>Test List and Price</vs-divider>
            <div class="vx-row mb-6">
                <div class="vx-col sm:w-1/3 w-full">
                <span>Gruop Test</span> 
                </div>
                <div class="vx-col sm:w-2/3 w-full">
                <v-select :options="group_option" placeholder="Select Grup Test" size="small" class="w-full" label="name" v-model="selected_group"></v-select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="vx-row mb-6">
                <div class="vx-col sm:w-1/3 w-full">
                <span>Price</span>
                </div>
                <div class="vx-col sm:w-2/3 w-full">
                <vs-input type="number" min="0"  oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" class="w-full" placeholder="IDR." v-model="form_data.sample_groups.price" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="vx-row mb-6">
                <div class="vx-col sm:w-1/3 w-full">
                <vs-select class="selectExample" label="Test Name" v-model="selected_test" autocomplete >
                <vs-select-item :key="index" :value="test.id" :text="test.name" v-for="test,index in test_option" />
                </vs-select>
                </div>
                <div class="vx-col sm:w-1/3 w-full">
                <vs-input class="inputx" placeholder="Min Req" label="Min Req" v-model="form_data.sample_groups.min_req" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="vx-col sm:w-1/3 w-full">
                <vs-input class="inputx" placeholder="Max Req" label="Max Req" v-model="form_data.sample_groups.max_req" required/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="vx-row">
                <div class="vx-col w-2/3" align="right">
                <vs-button class="mr-3 mb-2">Save</vs-button>
                <vs-button color="danger" type="border" class="mb-2" @click.prevent="form_data.name = null; form_data.sample_groups.id_group = null" >Cancel</vs-button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </vx-card>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
import vSelect from 'vue-select'

export default {
  name: 'MasterSample',
  components: {
    'v-select': vSelect,
  },
  data () {
    return {    
      api: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
      samples: [],
      selected: null,
      is_edit: false,
      is_add: true,
      card_title: 'Tambah Sample',

      form_data: {
        name: null,
        sample_groups: []
      },
      
      sample_groups:[],
      group_option: [],
      selected_group: null,

      test_option: [],
      selected_test: null,
  },
  methods: {
    getData: function(){
      let api = this.api + '/samples'

      this.$http.get(api)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status == 200) {
          this.samples = response.data
        }else {
          this.samples = []
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.$vs.notify({
          title:'Error!',
          text:'Terjadi kesalahan pada saat mengambil data.',
          color:'warning',
          iconPack: 'feather',
          icon:'icon-alert-circle'
        })
        console.log(error)
      })
    },
    getGroup: function(){
      let api = this.api + '/groups'
      this.$http.get(api)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status == 200) {
          this.group_option = response.data
        }else {
          this.samples = []
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.$vs.notify({
          title:'Error!',
          text:'Terjadi kesalahan pada saat mengambil data grup.',
          color:'warning',
          iconPack: 'feather',
          icon:'icon-alert-circle'
        })
        console.log(error)
      })
    },
    getTest: function(){
      let api = this.api + '/tests'
      this.$http.get(api)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status == 200) {
          this.test_option = response.data
        }else {
          this.test_option = []
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.$vs.notify({
          title:'Error!',
          text:'Terjadi kesalahan pada saat mengambil data test.',
          color:'warning',
          iconPack: 'feather',
          icon:'icon-alert-circle'
        })
        console.log(error)
      })
    },

    addData: function(){
      this.card_title = 'Tambah Data'
      this.is_edit = false
      this.selected = []
      this.is_add = true
    },
    handleSelected: function(){
      this.card_title = 'Edit Data'
      this.is_edit = true
      this.is_add = false

      this.form_data.nama = this.selected.nama
      this.form_data.sample_groups.price = this.selected.sample_groups.price
      this.form_data.sample_groups.min_req = this.selected.sample_groups.min_req
      this.form_data.sample_groups.max_req = this.selected.sample_groups.max_req
    },

    submitData: function(){
      let api
      if (this.is_add && !this.is_edit) {
        api = this.api + '/add-samples'
      }else {
        api = this.api + '/edit-samples/' + this.selected.id
      }
      
      this.$vs.loading()

      this.$http.post(api, this.form_data)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status == 200) {
          this.form_data = {
            nama: null,
            sample_groups:[]
          }
          this.selected_group = null
          this.addData()
          this.$vs.notify({
            title:'Berhasil!',
            text:'Data berhasil disimpan.',
            color:'success',
            iconPack: 'feather',
            icon:'icon-check',
            position:'top-right'
          })
          this.getData()
        }else {
          this.$vs.notify({
            title:'Error!',
            text:'Terjadi kesahalan pada saat menyimpan data.',
            color:'warning',
            iconPack: 'feather',
            icon:'icon-alert-circle',
            position:'top-right'
          })
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.$vs.notify({
            title:'Error ' +error.response.status,
            text:'Terjadi kesahalan pada saat menyimpan data.',
            color:'warning',
            iconPack: 'feather',
            icon:'icon-alert-circle',
            position:'top-right'
          })
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.$vs.loading.close()
      })
    }
  },
  created: function(){
    this.getData()
    this.getGroup()
    this.getTest()
  }
}

</script>
```

When i click submit only **name** that only succesfully added to the database and the **sample_groups** only showing empty array and all the data inside not added to the database. I know it's long question and bit confusing but i really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me which method is getting called when clicking save button?

Comment: hi sorry for the late reply method that i called is  **submitData** @YashMaheshwari